# macOS: How can a client application communicate with a Core Audio user space driver?

Tags: macos, audio, driver, core-audio

I'm currently working on a Core Audio user-space HAL plugin based largely on the "NullAudio" driver example provided by Apple. [(Here's a link to the example driver.)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AudioDriverExamples/Introduction/Intro.html)

I'm trying to figure out how a client application can communicate with the driver in order to configure it. So far I've tried using CFPreferences and CFNotificationCenter but neither work. In the latter case I can only communicate using the Darwin notification center, but its notifications cannot include any data other than the name of the notification, and consequently it's not useful for this purpose.

Given that the HAL driver is sandboxed, what method am I supposed to use to have a client application communicate with the driver?